# Connect TIMEDOUT error Salesforce CLI while trying to open org

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I am trying to authorize my org  but i am facing an error below any idea why the error occurs and how to resolve

> Starting SFDX: Open Default Org
>
> 20:13:52.519 sfdx force:org:open
> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 101.53.160.218:443
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
> errno: -4039,
> code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '101.53.160.218',
> port: 443
> }
> ERROR running force:org:open:  connect ETIMEDOUT 101.53.160.218:443
> 20:14:15.713 sfdx force:org:open
> ended with exit code 1

> 20:23:05.504 sfdx force:org:open
> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 101.53.160.218:443
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
> errno: -4039,
> code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '101.53.160.218',
> port: 443
> }
> ERROR running force:org:open:  connect ETIMEDOUT 101.53.160.218:443
> 20:23:28.231 sfdx force:org:open
> ended with exit code 1

Comment: Do you have any firewall setup at your network end? Recommend reviewing similar post from past - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186953/salesforce-dx-cli-connect-timedout

Comment: I don't have any firewall setup @Swetha

Comment: Check with the workaround provided over [this link](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/forcedotcom/cli/646/740898746), if it works for you