# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

Does anyone know what could cause this error after running pipeline, and how to fix that?

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xx:12345
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:12345:12) {
  errno: -110,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xxx.xxx.xx',
  port: 12345
}
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Metadata API request failed: connect ETIMEDOUT:  xxx.xxx.xx:12345
```

Interesting thing is that it didn't work last night (I had an error I mentioned) but today it works fine, there is no any error/issue.

Comment: Do you have any firewall setup at your network end? Try steps in https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/forcedotcom/cli/646/740898746 ,  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186953/salesforce-dx-cli-connect-timedout

Comment: Interesting thing is that it didn't work last night (I had an error I mentioned) but this morning it works fine, there is no any error/issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Temporary issue when the Salesforce API is timed out. **ETIMEDOUT** comes from the Node.js engine and the error implies

> ETIMEDOUT (Operation timed out): A connect or send request failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time. Usually encountered by HTTP or net. Often a sign that a `socket.end()` was not properly called.

Since this is a network issue there is not a lot you can do and wait for the network to be up. If you are not able to resolve it, then make sure your network connections are fine.